# Can someone identify this male Zygaenidae (subfamily Procridinae)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Photo taken in 2018, Near Berlinchen, Germany.

The immediate vincinity is *Calluna* on sands. The area has a an interesting vegetation with heather and broom, species-rich grasslands on poor and sometimes raw soil, and extensive pine forest areas with a lot of lichen. Different *Prunus* species (including *P. mahaleb* and, sadly, *P. serotina*) occur. In a flight range agricultural areas (some with rather rare weeds, possibly organic agriculture), but also lakes, rainage ditches, and marshlands. A bit further paludal forests and remnants of (mostly drained) mooreland exist. Some areas within possible flight range have deciduous forests with *Fagus*, *Quercus*, *Betula*, *Carpinus*, *Populus tremula*, and some rarer species (planted, including intrduced species).

[image]